# Python: command "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" doesn't work

Tags: python, shell, pip

I want to upgrade my pip, but if I type in "python -m pip install --upgrade pip", then my command shell says "cannot find 'python'". Python is already installed and my command shell can't detect the command "python", though.

Comment: Did you mean to use `python3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which version of python you are using:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Or:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Try that as I suspect you are using python 3 which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: pip3 install --upgrade pip will also do the job